# How to prove that $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal?. If, $MM^TU=U\Sigma^2$ and $M^TMV=V\Sigma^2$ then

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, diagonalization, svd

Let $M \in R^{m×n}$. In the context of the SVD theory, how to prove that $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal , If $U$ and $V$ are invertible and, $MM^TU=U\Sigma^2$,  $M^TMV=V\Sigma^2$.

Orthogonality definition:
If $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal then $U^{-1}=U^t$ and $V^{-1}=V^t$.

Comment: What's $M$? I guess it has to do with SVD?

Comment: This is not true. Consider $M=\Sigma=cI$ for some scalar $c$ for instance.

Comment: @Theorem You are right, it has to do with SVD. I just edited the context in the question.

Comment: @user1551 Dear, User, could you expand please a little your explanation about why this is not true?